# How do I download and upload files as effectively as possible using Python?

Tags: python, json, performance, memory-management, python-requests

So here is what I want to do: I want to download JSON files from an API, then I want to upload them to a container in Azure.

Here is my current solution: I use the module requests and

```
file = requests.get('<link>')
```

to download the data, which I then create a json file with and store it on my local computer like so

```
local_path = os.getcwd()
local_file_name = 'file'
open(local_file_name + '.json', 'wb').write(file.content)
```

then I find the local file, upload it to Azure, and delete the local file. This is a process I repeat for all the files, and I feel as if it is quite ineffective. Is there a better way to do it? I am wondering if I can upload the request files directly, with a specified name for every individual file, without having to store them locally. Thoughts?

Comment: Well if you need to optimize it for speed, spin up a simple web server (Flask, bottle, ...) that receives HTTP POST requests on certain port and instead of saving files to local machine, post in to your server. You should consider the security aspect also, so allow only your IP to post to that server, or use some authentication system (tokens).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `asyncio`, `async` and `aiohttp` to download files. One is for speed and the other for getting webpages like in requests. There is a fantastic article below about how to use `aiohttp` along with `async` and `asyncio`. I put it below.

https://www.queness.com/post/17688/aiohttp-tutorial-how-does-it-worka
Aiohttp tutorial

https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

asyncio/async tutorial